# Usage of (Reactive-) Events in Finalizers

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive, idisposable

I have the following business rule:
I have a license, that I receive from another programm, that needs to be used by a third programm. After the third programm acknowledges that it received the license I want to write it to a file for documentation purposes. If anything goes wrong (including the user closing the part of my application that is waiting for the response) I need to write the license back to the programm that send me the license, to store it there again. I am (for security Purposes I am told) not allowed to just safe the license (encrypted or not) into a file and call it a day.

The basic case, waiting for the other application to acknowledge the license is straightforward:

```
public bool UseKey(Func<string, bool> func, string serviceTag)
{
    Throw.IfNull(serviceTag, nameof(serviceTag));
    Throw.IfNull(func, nameof(func)); //Check if null

    if (func(_license)) //Programm acknowledged.
    {
        _keyUsed.OnNext(new UsedKey(serviceTag, _license)); //License was used. Therefore inform others that it can be written to file.
        return true;
    }
    return false; //Didn't work. Inform caller.
}
```

My idea for the case when something went wrong was the following:
I implement the `IDisposable` interface and in my Dispose(bool) method I'd send of the correct event informing the handler to write it properly back.

```
void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (!_keyWasUsed)
                _keyNotUsed.OnNext(_license);
            _keyUsed.Dispose();
            _keyNotUsed.Dispose();
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

The Problem I see is twofold.

1. If the client doesn't call the `Dispose` method I would not get informed that something went wrong.
2. If I put the call to the event into a finalizer I cannot know for sure that I could even fire an event anymore because maybe my references are already cleaned or the license field is already collected.

Therefore my Question(s): How can I issue an event or some kind of message (either Rx or even classic events if that makes anything easier) to some other executing code from a finalizer?

(Or is there a better approach than using `IDisposable` for this kind of work, that gives me the guarantee that either the operation succeeds or I can roll back (kinda like sql transactions)?)

Comment: You cannot access managed objects from the finalizer - there is no way to guarantee that a particular object will be alive at the time you try to access it (even if you have a strong reference to that object). A plain CLR event will also access managed objects - so no, you cannot fire events in the finalizer.

Comment: Thought as much. Any better Idea how you could approach my problem above?